# No AdminMenu in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a plugin, I have a page in that plugin that displays a list of registrations.

On that page I want to make a button to print that list of registrations.

When that button is clicked a new page is opened with an window.print(); in the body tag. The page is printed.

However, on that page, Wordpress places the admin menu en footer, which are also printed.

I would like to print that page without the admin menu en footer. So my question is: How can I create a page in my own plugin that does not show the Wordpress menu's but is just plain text

Comment: Please, explain "load a page in a plugin". Where's this button? Any relevant sample code?

Comment: changed the question, so hopefully it is a little clearer now

Comment: Yes, the goal is clear, but I'd like to see your current implementation for "a new page is opened", which page is that, how you're making it? Is it `add_submenu_page(null, /*etc*/);`?

Comment: yes it is add_submenu_page(null, /*etc*/);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While searching for brasofilo's solution to get working I found the use of the [GET variable noheader](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-admin/admin.php#L201).

That works great. Just add `&noheader` to your URL and you have no menus.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Custom Admin Screen in iframe Thickbox](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/76947/12615). We can open an admin page inside a Thickbox and prevent WP from rendering its elements.

The trick is to intercept the submenu page with the hook `load-$our_hidden_page_slug` and `exit` its execution before it loads the rest of WP.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'admin_menu_wpse_71437');
add_action( 'load-dashboard_page_my_hidden_page', 'intercept_thickbox_wpse_71437' ); 

/**
 * Add plugin page and a hidden and empty submenu page
 */
function admin_menu_wpse_71437() 
{
    add_menu_page(
        'TB', 
        '<span style="color:#e57300;">Thickbox</span>', 
        'edit_pages', 
        'open_hidden_page_in_thickbox', 
        'menu_page_wpse_71437',
        '', // no icon
        1 // create before Dashboard menu item
    );
    add_submenu_page(
        null, // doesn't shows up in the menu, attached to "index.php"
        'Hidden', 
        'Hidden', 
        'edit_pages', 
        'my_hidden_page', 
        'submenu_page_wpse_71437'
    );
}

/**
 * Main page
 */
function menu_page_wpse_71437() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    ?>
    <h2>Print without menu and footer</h2>
    <a href="#" id="open-tb"><strong>Print table</strong></a>
    <?php print_table_so_24054478(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
        $("#open-tb").click(function() {                 
            tb_show("", "index.php?page=my_hidden_page&TB_iframe=true");
            return false;
        });
    });             
    </script>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Submenu page
 */
function submenu_page_wpse_71437() { /* Do nothing */ }

/**
 * Intercept our hidden/empty page and print the Thickbox content
 */
function intercept_thickbox_wpse_71437() 
{ 
    iframe_header(); 
    echo '<script>window.print();</script>';
    print_table_so_24054478();
    exit; // Exit to prevent the page continueing loading and adding the admin menu's etc. 
}

/**
 * Aux function to echo a table
 * from https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style
 */
function print_table_so_24054478()
{
    echo <<<HTML
    <table class="widefat">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-title">Table header cell #1</th>
                <th>Table header cell #2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="row-title"><label for="tablecell">Table Cell #1, with label</label></td>
                <td>Table Cell #2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alternate">
                <td class="row-title"><label for="tablecell">Table Cell #3, with label and class <code>alternate</code></label></td>
                <td>Table Cell #4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="row-title">Table Cell #5, without label</td>
                <td>Table Cell #6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alt">
                <td class="row-title">Table Cell #7, without label and with class <code>alt</code></td>
                <td>Table Cell #8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="form-invalid">
                <td class="row-title">Table Cell #9, without label and with class <code>form-invalid</code></td>
                <td>Table Cell #10</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-title">Table header cell #1</th>
                <th>Table header cell #2</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
HTML;
}
```